# Log data from a real-time table in browser

Tags: javascript

Let's say there's a real-time table on a website (For example a Forex website). 
There would be one table and the cell value changes dynamically. There wouldn't be any input, it's just like a live update of the cell value.

I can get to the cell value using this code. (Tweaking the row and column indices for the data I want)

```
document.getElementById('cr1').rows[1].cells.item(2).innerHTML
```

I want to log the data every time a cell value changes. So, my idea was to write some event listener which gets fired every time the cell value changes and append the new data to an array variable and then to save it whenever I want. So, how can I write a function to automatically store this? Like is there a listener available?

I want to do this using the Console provided by Google Chrome.

Comment: Check out the `change` and `input` events for the input elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `DOMSubtreeModified` event

```
let arr=[]
document.getElementById('cr1').rows[1].cells[0].addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){
     arr.push(document.getElementById('cr1').rows[1].cells[2].innerHTML)
    });
```

```js
document.getElementById('tb').rows[1].cells[0].addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {

  console.log("Im changed");
});
document.getElementById('changeData').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  document.getElementById('tb').rows[1].cells[0].innerText = "Supercool";
});
document.getElementById('changeDataL').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  document.getElementById('tb').rows[1].cells[1].innerText = "Antarctia1";
});
```

```html
<table id="tb">
  <tr>
    <th>
      Name
    </th>
    <th>
      Location
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Superman
    </td>
    <td>
      Antarctica
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      John
    </td>
    <td>
      Iceland
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="changeData">Change superman</button><button id="changeDataL">Change antarctica</button>
```

Comment: It's actually pretty close to what I wanted. I tried it and found out that no matter which cell is updating, the data is getting pushed into the array. My requirement is that push data into array only if the cell I'm focusing on changes.
I tried something like this
`
document.getElementById('cr1').rows[1].cells[2].addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified',function()
`
and apparently it's not correct. Any suggestions?

Comment: is the cell that you are targeting is input type or span?

Comment: Hey @SreevathsaGowru i have edited the answer.it should work